# Defining a User with User.Identity.Name in controller constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization

For my actions that are going to interact with the User's account, I would like to create a "TheUser" object in addition to adding that object to "ViewData["TheUser"]" as soon as any action on my controller is called.

If the User is logged in, it will grab the User's info from the database, if not, "TheUser" object will just be null.

I tried accessing "User.Identity.Name" in the controller constructor, but it isn't created prior to any action being called.

I was looking at custom authorization filters, but those wouldn't allow me to create the "TheUser" object and store it in the ViewData.

This is a brief snippet of what I would like to accomplish:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    User TheUser;

    public HomeController()
    {
        TheUser = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? UserRepository.GetUser(User.Identity.Name) : null;

        ViewData["TheUser"] = TheUser;  
    }
}
```

Comment: this answer helped me for MVC3 http://stackoverflow.com/a/1506311/511438

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I created a custom base Controller class and added a "CurrentUser" property to it.

In the Initialize method, I placed the logic to get the user and then add it to the ViewData and the "CurrentUser" property of the controller.

I had my controllers inherit the custom base Controller class and I was able to reference "CurrentUser" variable anywhere in the controller:

```
public class CustomControllerClass : Controller
{
    public User CurrentUser { get; set; }

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);

        if (requestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string userName = requestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            CurrentUser = UserRepository.GetUser(userName);
        }

        ViewData["CurrentUser"] = CurrentUser;                
    }
}
```

Comment: When I inherited my Controller from a BaseController, my all web requests stop after executing the Execute method of BaseController and do not go to the Action methods. I get a blank page in the browser. Is there anything more we have to do for running this ?

Comment: Puneet, please take a look at my edit. My original answer was for ASP.NET MVC 1. I updated it to override the `Initialize` method as that is the accept place to do this sort of thing in MVC 2 and 3

Comment: Thank you so much, i really apreciated this. Looked for a long time, your answer was nice and concise.

Answer (score 5):

I setup my base controller in a similar way using the constuctor method, and I was able to read this User info on the following mannner. Note: I only store the UserId, not the User object, but the point of my code is to show how you can get the required info in the contriuctor method.

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    int _UserId = 0;

    public int UserId
    {
        get { return _UserId; }
        set { _UserId = value; }
    }

    public BaseController()
    {
        var userFromAuthCookie = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;

        if (userFromAuthCookie != null  && userFromAuthCookie.Identity.IsAuthenticated) // && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(userFromAuthCookie.Identity.Name))
        {
            busUser userBO = AceFactory.GetUser();
            string userNameFromAuthCookie = userFromAuthCookie.Identity.Name;
            _UserId = userBO.GetUserIdByUsername(userNameFromAuthCookie);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was also trying to return the user using User.Identity - `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal` fixed it for me - thanks very much

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal helped me access my user's Id in the actual constructor. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
public abstract class YourController : Controller
{
    public YourController()
    {
        var user = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;

        TheUser = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? UserRepository.GetUser(user.Identity.Name) : null;

        ViewData["TheUser"] = TheUser;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does the User have to be instantiated for every Controller action or just specific ones?

If you create an ActionFilterAttribute, you do have access to the Controller context. Not sure if that is true for AuthorizationFilters, but you could try something like this:

```
public class MyCustomFilter: ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["TheUser"] = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? UserRepository.GetUser(User.Identity.Name) : null;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Then, attach this to the necessary controller actions.

Comment: TheUser It is used for every action. What puzzles me is that although [Authorize] ensures the user is authenticated, I don't have access to User.Identity, but I can access ViewData.