# How to get User.Identity.Name from a controller?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to have some viewData info across all my views so I am following this tutorial

http://www.asp.net/LEARN/mvc/tutorial-13-cs.aspx

So I made my own applicationController but I need to get the UserName from the user.

Yet when I do this "HttpContext.User.Identity.Name" in the constructor it is always null. I am not sure why though.

Thanks

Ok the base thing did the trick.

```
  protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        Guid userId = coursesS.GetUserId(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    }
```

So that seems to work. The only thing now is it seems to go through this twice. Like I log in and it seems to do the this twice. I am guessing since this is like the equivalent of putting that code in every action. When I am loading up all these partial view on my site by calling them in my controller it does this.

So many I should cache it but I am not sure how though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try initializing stuff in the ApplicationController's Initialize method, HttpContext isn't avaliable in the constructor. Make sure to call base.Initialize() or you can get some interesting results.

Comment: where do I call this base.Initialze()? I am not sure where to stick it

Answer (score 7):

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Note the **.Current** that was missing from your call.

Comment: Hmm I might need to import something since I get this:

Error 3 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2):

Which specific property that you are accessing is null? You might want to check that User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true before checking the Name property. Also make sure that forms authentication is enabled and that you have indeed logged into the site first.

Comment: Good points.  Any of those issues would definietly cause the error described.

Comment: User is Null. That is what is null

Comment: Oh and ya I am logged in. If I take out that line and try to log in I go to authorized pages.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Page.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: Why the down vote? It works for me?  Although I'm happy to take the downvote if it means I'm learning something new...

Comment: Not sure why someone is voting you done. I tried it and I get this error: Error 3 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.User.get'

Comment: He's not on a Page.  He's creating a custom Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You're in a controller so use the following:

```
ControllerContext.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: Get this error when I try to do this in my abstract base controller.

Error 2 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext.HttpContext.get'

Comment: See Wyatt's comment above.  Make sure you call base.Initialize().

Comment: Where do I stick it in the constructor?

Comment: It also wants some parameter and I am not sure how to pass in what it wants.