# Can I access User.Identity.Name in the constructor of my controller? If not, what is best practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, business-logic

I have an ASP.NET MVC application where I initialize services in the constructor.  These services just point to another `.dll` in the project and are not WCF services.  I have displayed my code below:

```
[Authorise]
public class OrderController : Controller
{
    private OrderService _orderService;

    public OrderController()
    {
        _orderService = new OrderLogic(User.Identity.Name);
    }

    public ActionResult Search()
    {
        //do stuff here including calling _orderLogic.Search();
    }

    public ActionResult GetMyOrders()
    {
        //do stuff here including calling _orderLogic.GetMyOrders();
    }

    //more actions here
}

public class OrderService
{
    private string _username;

    public OrderLogic(string username)
    {
        _username = username
    }

    public List<Order> Search()
    {
        //use _username in query here
    }

    public List<Order> GetMyOrders()
    {
        //use _username in query here
    }

    //more methods here
}
```

The issue I have in the example above is that when I initialize `OrderService` I have to pass in the name of the logged-in user.  At this stage in the MVC lifecyle `User.Identity` is `null`.

I don't think there is a way to access the current user in the constructor.  I also don't really want to initialize the service in every action or pass in the current user to every method.  I am sure this scenario is common, what is best practice and what options do I have?

Comment: Basic question: Is the user logged in? Generally you would decorate your Order class or method with an [Authorise] attribute to prevent anonymous access.

Comment: i know that the user is logged in. I just don't have access to User.Identity in the constructor of a Controller (so i can't initialize OrderService).  I can access User.IDentity fine in actions.

Comment: Try initializing your service in Controller's Initialize method. This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506254/how-to-get-user-identity-name-from-a-controller. Or use IoC to inject a customer service in your constructor http://forums.asp.net/t/1467424.aspx?Access+to+User+Identity+in+Controller+constructor

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is tagged with the *dependency-injection* tag, here's the proper way of doing it using **Constructor Injection**. Inject the required service into your controller:

```
public class OrderController : Controller
{
    private OrderService _orderService;

    public OrderController(OrderService orderService)
    {
        _orderService = orderService;
    }

    public ActionResult Search()
    {
        //do stuff here including calling _orderLogic.Search();
    }

    public ActionResult GetMyOrders()
    {
        //do stuff here including calling _orderLogic.GetMyOrders();
    }

    //more actions here
}
```

Compose `OrderController` instances in your application's [Composition Roo](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot)t. As explained in detail in [my book](http://amzn.to/12p90MG), with ASP.NET MVC you do this by implementing [`IControllerFactory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.icontrollerfactory) (which is easiest by deriving from [`DefaultControllerFactory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultcontrollerfactory)):

```
public class CompositionRoot : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(
        RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == typeof(OrderController))
        {
            return new OrderController(
                new OrderService(
                    requestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name));
        }

        // handle other Controller types here...
    }
}
```

Register your custom `IControllerFactory` with [`SetControllerFactory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbuilder.setcontrollerfactory).