# Deriving Controller from a BaseController, then Action methods do not execute and response is blank

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I wanted to create a CurrentUser object to be accessible in every Action of Controller, I initialized it in Constructor but User.Identity was not available in Constructor. I followed the following link on stackoverflow:

[Defining a User with User.Identity.Name in controller constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313190/defining-a-user-with-user-identity-name-in-controller-constructor)

But after inheriting my Controllers from BaseController, my Action methods are not even executed, the execution stops at Execute of BaseController and I get blank pages in the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the `Execute` override in the linked post.  It is missing the call to `base.Execute(context)`.  This means that there is no call being made to `Controller.ExecuteCore()`, which means that no call is being made to `ActionInvoker.InvokeAction(context,actionName)`, which is why your action methods don't execute and your response is blank.

Add `base.Execute(context)` to the end of your `Controller.Execute()` override.

Comment: Thanks, in the meantime, I was able to catch this and solved the problem!!